# Changed permissions of su

Tags: command-line

I accidentally changed permissions of `/usr/bin/su` by `chmod 744 su`, and am not able to become root any more.

How can I change the permissions back?

Answer (score 2):

Reboot with a Live DVD and reset the permissions to what they need to be. By the way: there is no `su` in `/usr/bin/` so you might need to re-examine what you actually did.

There is one in `/bin/`. Should be set to:

```
ls -l su
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 36936 jul 18  2014 su
```

That would be `chmod 4755 /bin/su`